# How to stop input text from being copied on the other window session?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I run 2 sessions on localhost with Browsersync.
When I write something on one window, it's immediately being copied to the other window.

Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its because I'm using Browsersync XD. Solved.